# Close responsive responsive-leftbar on button click jquery C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

**CSS**

```
 .responsive-leftbar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #112b39;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: -50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
```

**HTML tag for div**

```
 <div id="responsivediv" class="responsive-leftbar">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
 </div>
```

**HTML tag for button**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnlogout"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ForeColor="Black"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Logout</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    $('#lbtnlogout').toggle(    
      function() {
         $('#responsivediv').css('left', '0')
      }, function() {
          $('#responsivediv').css('left', '200px')
     })
</script>
```

**Modal on button click**

```
  <div class="modal fade col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2" style="background-color:transparent; border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; margin-left:33%; margin-top:4%;" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:7%; width:80%; border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="margin-left:-7%; width:120%;">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#2C74C5;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <br />

        </div>
          <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#2C74C5; margin-top:15px;">
           <center>   <p style="font-size:14px;">If You Logout, Your Following Information Will Be Removed</p></center>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top:10px;">
          <center>
            <p style="color:black;">1) Google Information</p>
            <br />
         <p style="color:black;"><asp:Label ID="lblgooglename" runat="server" Text="Your Google Login Credential."></asp:Label></p>
            <br />
            <p style="color:black;">2) Logged In As</p>
            <br />
            <p style="color:black;"><asp:Label ID="lblname2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
            <br />
            <p style="color:black;">3) Your Role</p>
            <br />
            <p style="color:black;"><asp:Label ID="lblrole2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
            <br />
            <br />
            </center>
        </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#2c74c5; margin-top:-0px;">
                   <center>       
                       <p style="color:black; font-size:14px; margin-left:-25px; color:white;">Press No If You Don't Wish To Logout, Or Else Press Logout</p>
                   </center>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#2C74C5; margin-top:15px;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="btnlogout_Click">NO</button>
             <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning active" Text="Logout" OnClick="btnlogout_Click" />
        </div>

      </div>
```

I am creating a web app in which i have a side navbar it is working fine on big screen but in small screen i want to close the navbar on button click but it is not working i try the following code but i am not able succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `OnClick` attribute for your button to `btnlogout_Click`, but I don't see a `btnlogout_Click` function. If that script is being loaded when the DOM loads, then `#lbtnlogout` will be toggled when the page loads, but at no other time.

I think all you need to do is put the toggle code in a function.

```
<script>
    function btnlogout_Click() {
        $('#lbtnlogout').toggle(    
          function() {
             $('#responsivediv').css('left', '0')
          }, function() {
              $('#responsivediv').css('left', '200px')
         });
     }
</script>
```